# How to fix -- IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is set to 8.0 when Permission Handler already in my Podfile?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

Hi:  I have the above error message. I have done the basic:

changed AppFrameworkInfo.plst to 9.0
Uncommented 9.0 in pod file

but still get this message for each package in my pub spec.

```
  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target  'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.9
```

There are multiple pages (including on SO) saying that to fix this you need to add the following to the end of the pod file.

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
  end
 end
end
```

My issue is I use the permissions handler package which already has a modified pod file to work around which permissions are included in the final package:

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
target.build_configurations.each do |config|


  # Here are some configurations automatically generated by flutter

  # You can remove unused permissions here
  # for more infomation: https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/develop/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
  # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
  config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
    '$(inherited)',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
    'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
    'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
    'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
    'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
    # 'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
    'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
    'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=0',

    ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
    'PERMISSION_LOCATION=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
    'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
    'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
    'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0'
  ]


    end
  end
end
```

But I can't work out where to include the code to fix the Deployment target.  Wherever I paste it in, I get an error (a different one... not the deployment error).  I figured out I can't have 2 `post_install do` lines so I think I need to cut the `config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'` line but wherever I paste it, it doesn't seem to work.

Permission handler is popular so I figure someone might have run into this before me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
target.build_configurations.each do |config|

  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'

  # Here are some configurations automatically generated by flutter

  # You can remove unused permissions here
  # for more infomation: https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/develop/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
  # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
  config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
    '$(inherited)',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
    'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
    'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
    'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
    'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
    # 'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
    'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
    'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=0',

    ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
    'PERMISSION_LOCATION=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
    'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
    'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=0',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
    'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0'
  ]


    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think so but will try again now.  Should I run flutter clean when chaining profile?

Comment: Ok flutter clean but gives the following `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description`

Comment: That worked (I don't think I had the spacing right first time) thanks!